# python script for convert video to image sequence using FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have 100 uncompressed mov (Video files) and i want to convert all mov to sgi image sequences.

i have a list of all mov file path.

how to convert .mov (video) to .sgi (image sequence) using [python](https://www.python.org/) and [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use ffmpeg to convert the video to sgi images using this ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo outputFrames_%04d.sgi
```

-replace inputVideo your input file path and name

-replace outputFrames with output file path and name

-replace '4' in _%04d with the number of digits you want for sequential image file naming.

now one way to process your files from python is to launch ffmpeg as a subprocess and providing the command you want executed by ffmpeg:

```
import subprocess as sp
cmd='ffmpeg -i inputVideo outputFrames_%04d.sgi'
sp.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

remember to use double \ in your file path in the cmd command string (at least for me on windows).
If you want to loop over 100 movie files, write a loop that concatenates the command string with the appropriate input and output file names.